# Getting error while deploying smart contract using truffle

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, binance-smart-chain

```
2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

   Replacing 'SimpleStorage'
   -------------------------
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({
  code: -32603,
  message: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  data: { originalError: { code: 'ETIMEDOUT', connect: true } },
  stack: 'Error: ETIMEDOUT\n' +
    '    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\\Downloads\\eattheblocks-master\\screencast\\321-connect-frontend-contract-bsc\\node_modules\\request\\request.js:848:19)\n' +
    '    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)\n' +
    '    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)'
})
    at Web3ProviderEngine.emit (events.js:364:17)
    at D:\Downloads\eattheblocks-master\screencast\321-connect-frontend-contract-bsc\node_modules\@trufflesuite\web3-provider-engine\index.js:57:14
```

- Truffle v5.4.3 (core: 5.4.3)
- Solidity - 0.8.0 (solc-js)
- Node v14.17.3
- Web3.js v1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ganache is running if you are using that. Also provide your truffle config file and migration file for more information.